# For loop to overwrite a value inside a column - R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm currently working on my uni project and I'm trying to prepare my data.
I added a new column to store the name of the group where sorted elements belong.
I have given it a default value of NA, now I am trying to overwrite it using a for loop so that it displays a proper name of each element's group.
I've been trying to change my loops multiple times and see what could work, but nothing seems to - the output I get doesn't change and the value of the group remains NA.
Here's my code:

```
dane2<-dane[,-c(3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)]
Grupa<-NA
dane2<-cbind(dane2, Grupa)
```

```
k1<-kob1chol[sample(nrow(kob1chol), 15),]
  for (i in k1){
    Grupa[dane2$Grupa] <- "K1"
  }
k2<-kob2chol[sample(nrow(kob2chol), 15),]
  for (i in k2){
    Grupa[dane2$Grupa] <- "K2"
  }
m1<-mez1chol[sample(nrow(mez1chol), 15),]
  for (i in m1){
    dane2$Grupa[dane2$Grupa] <- "M1"
  }
m2<-mez2chol[sample(nrow(mez2chol), 15),]
  for (i in m2){
    dane2$Grupa[dane2$Grupa] <- "M2"
  }
```

And here's a sample of my output:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrR0O.png)

I'd be grateful for all advice, thank you in advance!

Change the NA value to the name of the group (K1, K2, M1, M2)

Comment: you might start with trying dane2$Grupa[i] <- "K1" instead of Grupa[dane2$Grupa] <- "K1".

Comment: @AbdurrahmanYavuz unfortunately doesn't work either

Comment: what is the value of "k1" is it iterable?

Comment: I don't have an idea what is inside your 'dane' ; so I wont attempt to help you beyond telling you a way to identify a bad for loop. if there is a loop , for `i` in *whatever* and in the body of the loop {} no mention is made of the `i` ; the loop is no good.